# Годится ли такое проектирование в mongodb?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется такая бд в реляционном виде. Пытаюсь ее подвести к формату mongodb. Подскажите как лучше спроектировать такую бд в mongo. Не пойму, как правильно хранить оценки по дисциплине у студента?

У меня получилось так:

student { _id: .., lname: .., fname: .., mname: .., passport: { num: .., seria: ..}, attests: [ { discname: .., mark: ..}, { .. }, .. ] }

group { _id: .., num: .., students: [ ObjectId(..), .. ], disciplines: [ ObjectId(..), .. ], }

discipline { _id: .., name: .., groups: [ ObjectId(..), .. ], }